# Gradle plugin categorisation

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

A custom gradle plugin when listed using `gradle tasks` is listed as `Other tasks`.

Example - `gradle tasks`

```
IDE tasks
---------
cleanIdea - Cleans IDEA project files (IML, IPR)
idea - Generates IDEA project files (IML, IPR, IWS)

Other tasks
-----------
csvDiffTask - my custom task
```

How can a different category be given, example `My Tasks`, so that when running `gradle tasks` it appears as below

```
IDE tasks
---------
cleanIdea - Cleans IDEA project files (IML, IPR)
idea - Generates IDEA project files (IML, IPR, IWS)

My tasks
-----------
csvDiffTask - my custom task
```

PS: Checked the source of some plugins on github and checked stackoverflow and no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by setting the "group" property of your 'csvDiffTask'. Have a look at the Gradle DSL reference for details:  http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.Task.html#org.gradle.api.Task:group for details

cheers,
René

Comment: Thanks. For others viewing this, the code was `target.task('csvDiffTask', group:'AddOnJavaAntTasks', description: 'blah', type: CsvDiffTask)` in the plugin.groovy file.